# Accessing Transitent Attribute from Child View Object ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have creating a view link between a parent and child VO. I can successfully retrieve a parents attribute in order to set the childs VO to the same attribute but that only works for attributes which aren't transient. It doesn't matter if I use a groovy expression or retrieve the values from the VORowimpl the transient attributes I am trying to access that are in the parent VO return null. Is there anyway to get those values?

Comment: Are those transient values "updatable" in your VO ? Where are you trying to access those values ? In a bean ? In the model ?

Comment: They are set to updateable. I basically created a master detail relationship of say a department as a parent that has many employees. I run it in the application module with that parent having some transient attribute say nickname. If I create a new department with employees, and I set a nickname none of the employee childs ever receive the nickname values if I set the an attribute in employee to a groovy expresion pointing to that parent nickname. I use a viewlink departmentVL.nickname to try and access the value. It just returns null.

Comment: The ViewLink accessor works for non transient attributes of the departments table. I also tried accessing in the rowimpl. I know the child table receives access to the parent through a getRow function but it has the same result. Only non transient attributes return a value. The nick name transient returns null. The only work around I've found is to set the children on the parent rowimpl by using its rowiter for getting children. That only works when setting the value of the transiet, I get the value use rowiter and set the children. But it only works on set of the transient attribute.